# The distance between $P,$ a plane and a point $(0,0,0)$ is $6.$ Find $t_0.$

Tags: calculus

> Let $P$ be a normal plane to the curve $x(t) = 2 \cos t, \quad 
>    y(t) = 2 \sin t, \quad
>    z(t) = - t, \quad 
>    -\infty < t < \infty$ in $\left( \rule{0pt}{12pt} x(t_0),y(t_0),z(t_0)\right)$.
> The distance between $P$ and a point $(0,0,0)$ is $6.$
> Find $t_0.$

My attempt:

$x'(t)=-2\sin(t) , y'(t)=2\cos(t), z'(t)=-1.$

Substitute $t=t_0 \implies x'(t_0)=-2\sin(t_0) , y'(t_0)=2\cos(t_0), z'(t_0)=-1$.

The distance between a point and a plane is $$d=\frac{|ax+by+cz+d|}{\sqrt{{a^2+b^2+c^2}}}$$ $$\implies 
6=\frac{|-2\sin(t_0)x+2\cos(t_0)y-z+d|}{\sqrt{{(-2\sin(t_0))^2+(2\cos(t_0))^2+1}}} $$
$$\underset{(x,y,z)=(0,0,0)}{\implies} 
d=6\sqrt5.$$

The formula of $P$ is $$-2\sin(t)x+2\cos(t)b-z+6\sqrt5=0$$

How to find $t_0?$

Appreciate any help.

Comment: When you say "vertical plain", do you mean "normal plane"?

Comment: @Arthur yes....

Comment: It is a pity that you used $d$ to refer to two different things, The key to this problem is that the parameter $d$ in the equation if the plane depends on $t_0$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The equations of the planes are...
$$-2\sin(t)x+2\cos(t)y-z+6\sqrt5=0$$
When $t = t_0$, the point $\left( 2\cos(t_0), 2\sin(t_0), -t_0\right)$ is on the plane, so we have...

$$-4\sin(t_0)\cos(t_0)+4\cos(t_0), \sin(t_0)+t_0+6\sqrt5=0$$

$$\implies t_0 = -6\sqrt 5$$